# iOS - Turning my Dates into Hyperlinks

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css, ipad

For some reason I could not really find anything on this topic.  I'm fairly certain I am not the only one having this issue, perhaps I'm just not using the correct search terms.

My problem is that iOS is turning strings (I have a dates that are display fields).

For example: 10/4/2011, 12/6/2001 turn into hyperlinks (of course they don't go anywhere), but you can select them and try to add to your contacts or copy.  I'd like the string to not be hot.

What's super strange is 10/18/2011 ISN't hot, I guess the pattern is (starts with 1 and has 9 characters, similar to a phone number)

Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry folks I should have mentioned I am displaying the data within a browser.

Comment: Where are you displaying these strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tag in your header might work. It stops numbers from behaving like their a phone number or an address.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

If it doesn't work, try these also:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the `dataDetectorTypes` property. This determines what links will be formed automatically.

Comment: Here is a link.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDataDetectorTypes

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is actually being rendered within the browser I believe your link is for iOS apps.

Comment: Sorry about that! I won't delete my answer, though; it's wrong for *your* case, but someone might find their way to this question and be helped somehow. :)